# searching for phrase having spaces like "famous for" using php

Tags: php

I have text files and i am searching for specific phrases in it like "famous for" or "born on". i need the position of text only but don't know how to do it
i've tried

```
$string = "some string that has famous for or born on in it";
var_dump(strpos($string,"famous for"));
```

but it is not giving me the result;

```
preg_match("/famous for/",$string,$found);
var_dump($found);
```

it is returning null. anyone please help...

Comment: What is the expected output here?

Comment: i want the position of "famous for" phrase

Comment: i can use strpos() function but it is not searching two words i want to search for "famou for"

Comment: The code you posted does exactly that. It outputs "int(21)" which is correct. How is your expected output different from that?

Comment: check the demo that I've created.

Answer (score 0):

you're messing somewhere else,
I executed the code and it works fine for me, though I've added [`stripos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) to match case-insensitive strings.

From manual,

> stripos — Find the position of the first occurrence of a case-insensitive substring in a string.

make sure you've `PHP` version `5+` at least.

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/BFfvEE)**